# How to run sumfony bin/console cmds always on prod mode

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu

The question is: **how to force php bin/console ..some cmd.. to run as prod environment Always !!!**
I know about option --env=prod at the end all is clear, but how to configure symfony 3.4 on production server to run all with env=prod ???

I will explain situation more **detailed** when i run in symfony 3.4

> php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction

I get errors about not installed dev dependency lib's which are required in AppKernel
with if condition

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        //...
}
```

So basically as i runned **SYMFONY_ENV=prod composer install --no-dev** with --no-dev i don't have dev dependances installed, and above migration comamdn fails here.

Answer (score 1):

In your `bin/console` file find this line (where your kernel is instantiated):

`$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool)$_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);`

or similar and replace it with this one:

`$kernel = new Kernel('prod', false);`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i don't want to barcode it in file but instead hardcore somewhere in environment in Linux isntace. In my console i see - **$env = $input->getParameterOption(['--env', '-e'], getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');** is there any way to set SYMFONY_ENV variable globally, do you know ?

Comment: @Armen Well you can `export APP_ENV=prod` but that's turning into linux system question. I don't know which setup you use, if it's a server or local machine, docker or virtual machine... 
How to manage env vars in Linux: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/ 
Which variable symfony uses: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#selecting-the-active-environment

Comment: I was working on Ubuntu used this command: **export SYMFONY_ENV=prod** all worked, Thanks for help

Comment: @Armen That might be only temporary solution. For a more permanent, check the link I've posted and see how to export variable from `.bashrc` or `.*rc` files.

Answer (score 1):

So for me correct answer was.

Inject to

**/etc/profile** file at bottom

**export SYMFONY_ENV=prod**

and in that case you will not to add --env=prod avery time after each php bin/console command

This is fully working with **Symfony 3.4**